# Grep certain files only

Tags: linux, perl, cgi

How can I get a list of certain files read into an array.

I have several files that are structured like this:

```
12345_lrg.jpg
12445_sml.jpg
14445_sml.jpg
12345_lrg.jpg
42345_lrg.jpg
```

I need to only get the "_sml.jpg" returned into a array.

Comment: Is your problem with reading the file list, or filtering the array?

Comment: Why the cgi tag? You should probably explain a lot more about your question and show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for perl code, as your tags imply, then you would typically use [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html):

```
my @all = qw(
    12345_lrg.jpg
    12445_sml.jpg
    14445_sml.jpg
    12345_lrg.jpg
    42345_lrg.jpg
);

my @sml = grep /_sml\.jpg$/i, @all;
```

Comment: But the tags also say "linux", so why `/i`? :-)

Comment: @melpomene Why not? It's not like you would get a false match if a user uploaded a file with `.JPG` extension.